# Как выявить какие записи m:n были стерты?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Вот ситуация, Есть таблица с элементами (`element`), элементы могут быть разного типа (`element_type`), есть свойства присущие элементам (`prop`), причем у каждого типа элемента есть свой набор свойств (**m:n** `type_has_prop`), значение свойства для конкретного элемента задается в `element_prop_value`. Так же, `prop` имеет флаг `is_finite`, что значит, что ему присуще строго ограниченное, конечное количество значений (например типы корпусов у элементов), все возможные варианты для каждого свойства фиксируются в таблице `prop_finite_value`, однако, разным типам элементов присущи разные типы корпусов, каким типам какие значения свойств присущи определяется в таблице `element_type_has_prop_finite_value`.

[image: EER]

Теперь к проблеме, я, очевидно, где-то накосячил в работе приложения и произошла неприятность. Допустим в `element_prop_value` есть запись о том, что у элемента Х есть свойство - тип корпуса со значением **0805**, это зафиксированно жестко, просто записано в виде чарфилда, так же у нас есть запись в таблице `prop_finite_value`, что мол де свойство **тип корпуса** может принимать вот такие значения и там действительно присутствует значение **0805**, НО, проблема в том, что в таблице `element_type_has_prop_finite_value` в результате работы приложения куда-то пропала запись, что у такого-то типа элементов существует вариант выбрать вот такой-то тип корпуса, причем, как я понял, случай не единичный, просто спохватились когда не нашли в комбобоксе в интерфейсе самого часто-используемого типа корпуса... В итоге, я хочу сделать такой запрос к базе, который бы выбрал все значения `value` из таблицы `element_prop_value` и проверил бы, наличие у типа элемента соответствующего `finite` свойства...
Как джоинами можно связать такую кашу?

Comment: у вас 2 таблицы с именем `finite`. в какой искать?

Comment: @NovitskiyDenis дел в том, что надо искать "отсутствие" записи в таблице element_type_has_prop_finite_value, вот у меня мозг и взрывается, если есть запись в element_prop_value, то должна быть и связка в element_type_has_prop_finite_value

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из схемы, записи, которые есть в `element_prop_value`, но которых нет в `element_type_has_prop_finite_value` ищутся так:

```
select e.id_prop, e.id_element, e.value
from element_prop_value e
left join prop_finite_value p on e.id_prop=p.id_prop
left join element_type_has_prop_finite_value et on p.id=et.id_prop_finite_value
where et.id_prop_finite_value is null
```